# Is there any event for after clicking proceed to check out?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to check additional checking with the product that has already been added in the cart, is there any method of event observers for doing this,  our intention is to find out the customer who has added the product when it is in offer time frame, and after that time frame they should not want to proceed check out that product.

Comment: how about this event controller_action_predispatch

Comment: Yes. that will work too.

Comment: I got this controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index

Answer (score 1):

To do some logic before placing the order, you can use the event

`sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`

available in `/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement` before placing the order.

Or in worst case, you can also override the `/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/SaveOrder` Controller, do your stuff before the line `$this->getOnepage()->saveOrder();` which is responsible for saving the order.

Comment: @Naveen have you tried this?